# What percent of tablet users browse in portrait vs. landscape orientation?

Tags: android, ipad, statistics, tablet, screen-orientation

iPad and various Android tablets have been out for awhile now, but I haven't been able to find the answer to this question:  When using tablets, which orientation is used most often, especially for Web browsing?

My specific need is to optimize the UI for a mobile Web app, but I was hoping to have some stats to start from... while I'm familiar with where to find monitor size stats in general, I've found nothing specifically about tablets (size or orientation).

My *hunch* is that most users browse the web in **portrait** orientation, but I'd like some numbers to back that up to some business folks.

Yes, I'm well aware that a) "market stats"can be deceiving and b) responsive design dictates I'll need to design a decent experience for landscape users as well... again, was just hoping to find some numbers or common wisdom to help justify my UI design direction.

Comment: I personally use landscape, but I would assume that most users use portrait.

Comment: I think that most of the smartphones are used in portrait and most of the tablets in landscape

Comment: this might help https://brooksreview.net/2011/09/tablet-power/

Answer (score 0):

This is from 2017, but I can't find anything more current.

[image: 1]

Answer (score -3):

84% of tablet users prefer to use it in landscape, probably because it is more similar to a computer screen. Also, most of the time the keyboard and videos are larger and easier to use,

Comment: What's your source for that number?